# email alert for product availability

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, mysql

I want to give the user the possibility to click a button when the product stock is 0.

the idea is to send an email to the user as soon has the product has been restablished.

I can make this farely easy by doing a table, writting a function and sending and email, more or less like this, right.  However I would like to know if wordpress has any function or funcionallity to do exactly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this called waitlist you can use this free [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/waitlist-woocommerce/)

Comment: this plugin does exactly what is pretended. Thanks!.

Comment: never mind, don't forget to vote as correct answer ;)